# Nomad periodic job starts immediately

Tags: scheduled-tasks, nomad

I have a nomad periodic job that has this in the job config:

```
periodic {
  cron = "* */2 * * *"
  prohibit_overlap = true
}
```

However, I find that when nomad finishes running the job (the job takes less than two hours), it more or less immediately starts it again (sometimes within 60 seconds).  I expected it to start it after about two hours.

Why does that happen, and how can I make nomad start the job only every two hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have * in minutes field, so your job will start every minute. You should change cron to 0 */2 * * *.

Comment: Forehead-slapping moment here